# searchDisplayController dim view stays after first search

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate, uisearchresultscontroller

I am using `searchDisplayController` for search functionality. On the click of the search button, I do folowing thing:

```
[mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

First time, everything works fine. I do following in *searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch* (which will be called on cancel button event)

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
  [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Now, on cancel button press, search bar hides also. Till that moment everything works fine. Now when second time I press search icon, search bar opens and even-though  I type text and get search results, the dim view stays there.

I don’t know the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !!!

Actually I was making a tiny mistake in order to hide/show the `Tableview` of `search display controller` as following:

```
-(IBAction)searchButton_Action:(id)sender
{
    //
    //
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = FALSE;
    //
    //
}
```

We should not do this on our own programatically because `searchDisplayController` itself manages its `TableView`.